# Css grid minmax wrap

Tags: css, css-grid

I have the following grid with 3 items:

```
<div class="grid">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<button>&nbsp;</button>
</div>

.grid {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-end;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 1fr)  minmax(200px, 1fr) minmax(100px, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 2rem;
}
```

I want the paragraphs to be at least 200px as from css minmax and the button to be at least 100px and wrap as a decrease the browser window width.

but this doesnt happen.

The elements stay in one row.

Thank you

Comment: CSS-Grids don't wrap like that You need to use media queries to adjust the columns....or just use flexbox.

Comment: Thats not correct, if I use repeat with auto-fill it wraps.

Comment: ...but you're not are you? Which is my point.

Answer (score 0):

Close enough to what you wanted (without media queries and convoluted rules not worth the trouble):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Delor sit</p>
  <button>Amet</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
// See the container's items:
.container > * { background: lightblue; }
```

A) Use **grid**; don't know if possible to set different minmax() while preserving repeat(auto-fit, ..) behavior:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}
```

B) Use **flexbox**; the margins hack mimicks grid's gutters until CSS implements flexbox gutters natively:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -2rem;
}
.container > * { margin-right: 2rem; }

p { flex: 1 1 200px; }

button { flex: 1 1 100px; }
```